# Super specie nihil?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Help!
There are the well-known terms sub specie dei, sub specie aeternitatis (Spinoza?).
I want to know: how would one correctly write super specie nihil, meaning not "below", from the (above) view of God/eternity, but above "nothingness"?

I am with small Greek and less Latin, so I may not be worthy of substantial reply. But, I want to know what would be the contrary/contrasting idea in Latin to sub specie dei, sub specie aeternitatis?
Can someone help me?

Comment: What is your intended meaning? Sub specie dei means "under the gaze of God", i.e. from God's perspective; are you hoping for something like "under the gaze of nothingness"?

Comment: Can you give an example of something that you would say or see from the perspective that you have in mind?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. What I am wanting to say is perhaps: over/above the gaze of nothing(ness). The idea of sub specie dei, views All from the "higher", divine perspective. What I would like to know is how one might write: not "under" the gaze/perspective of God (which traditionally includes creator/ion, the world), but the idea that the world is "above" (coming out of), nothing (nihil). So less a sentence that contrasting world-views summarized in terms: sub specie dei vs super nihil. How would this be written correctly? (ideally it would be a neat contrast or symmetrical terms.) :)